# UseQuery on change using e.target.value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo

I have a graphql query and I need to update and call getData on every input change. I've tried using useState but the state does not update in time. The only thing I can imagine to fix this is using e.target.value as the value for the variable but I can't just add the useQuery inside the event handler because it's a hook. My question is, how can I use the e.target.value as a variable in my graphql query.

```
query getData($email:String!){
checkoutProfile(email: $email){
userProfileId,
userProfile {
        email
}
  }
  
}
```

My tsx code

```
  const handleInputValue = (e: any) => {
const da = useLazyQuery( getData, {
  variables: {
    email: e.target.value // not working because it's inside a event handler
  },
  ssr: false,
  pollInterval: 500,
})
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have to make another state for `e.target.value`?

Comment: @caTS If i use a state the fetch will always be one value behind the e.target.value

Comment: `useLazyQuery` will provide you a function that you can call for the fetch which will accept variables